# Opencart 2.x - Customer Group ID comes back as 0

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm trying to call the customer group ID in the payment method and shipping method controllers.

I'm using the following code:

```
//groupId
$this->load->language('account/account');

if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
                $data['groupId'] = $this->customer->getGroupId();
} elseif ($this->config->get('config_customer_group_id')) {
                $data['groupId'] = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
}
```

When called in the template like so:

```
<p>GroupID: <?php echo (int)$groupId ?></p>
```

It returns as:

GroupID: 0

When the intended groupID is 4.

The signed in user is assigned to a group with the ID of 4.

What i'm trying to do is make the additional comments field required to a certain customer group.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use following code

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {  
  $data['groupId'] = $data['groupId'] = $this->customer->getGroupId(); 
} elseif (isset($this->config->get('config_customer_group_id'))) {
   $data['groupId'] = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id'); 
} else {    
  $data['groupId'] = 0; 
}
```

When called in the template like so:

```
<p>GroupID: <?php echo $groupId ?></p>
```

It returns as:Your customer groupID

The signed in user is assigned to a group with the ID of you want.

I think above code is working..